# convert to percentage

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell with text and number (`abc123`).
I like to change only number 123 to percentage (`abc12.3%`).
Is it possible to do?
Thank you.

Comment: How do you know it's 12.3% and not 1.23% or 123% or .123%?

Comment: is your data always three letters followed by a three digit number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific example you can use [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) function `SUBSTITUTE(Text,Old_text,New_text)`.

**Text**    Required. The text or the reference to a cell containing text for which you want to substitute characters.

**Old_text**    Required. The text you want to replace.

**New_text**    Required. The text you want to replace old_text with.

Try this:

put `abc123` in cell `A1`
and in cell `A2` this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1)/10&"%")
```

**Text:** `A1`

**Old_text:** `RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1)`

**New_text:** `RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1)/10&"%"`

`RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1)` extracts the number. You can do whatever operation with the number like `/1000` and also use the function `ROUND` it will be:

`ROUND(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1)/1000,2)` = `0.12`

The final function will be:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1),ROUND(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1)/1000,2)&"%")
```

Comment: Thank you. This SUBSTITUTE function is working well.

Comment: One quick , use the same SUBSTITUTE function  above, can we round up 2 decimal (0.123% become 0.12%). Thank you.

Comment: Yeah sure, check my answer again.

Comment: Wow, it works, but the % is missing at the end on ROUND(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1)/1000,2). Can you help. Thank you.

Comment: I got it. Thanks